# Elliptic differential equation

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

Given the following elliptic differential equation:
$$ - \nabla \cdot (\lambda \nabla u ) = f$$ in $\Omega$
$$ \lambda \nabla u \cdot n = b - au $$ on $\partial \Omega$

where $\Omega$ is a bounded field with smooth edge and $\lambda, f, a, b$ smooth functions with $ \lambda \geq \lambda_0 > 0$ and $a \geq a_0 > 0$.

Is there any equivalent minimization problem to this boundary value problem?

Comment: Can we allow $f = \nabla \cdot g$, where $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$? In this case, then it's fairly straightforward (and the problem reduces to a minimization problem with constraints). I'm not sure this can be written as a simple functional if $f$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Hi Guillermo! Thanks for your comment. So, if $ f = \nabla \cdot g$ (I think we can allow this ;) ), what would be an equivalent minimization problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the notion that DMan mentioned above, then we can rewrite this problem as, allowing $f = \nabla\cdot g$,
$$
\|\lambda \nabla u+g\|_2^2.
$$

Stationarity of this problem implies that (as a heuristic derivation without lagrange multipliers for the boundary conditions, which can be included later),
$$
0 = 2\nabla\cdot (\lambda \nabla u + g) = 2(\lambda \nabla^2 u + \nabla\cdot g) \implies -\lambda \nabla^2 u = \nabla\cdot g = f,
$$
which is roughly what we wanted. This problem can then be written as
$$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{u}{\text{minimize}}
& & \|\lambda \nabla u+g\|_2^2 \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \lambda \nabla u\cdot n = b-au, \text{ over } \partial\Omega.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$$

The latter constraint is linear, and the functional above is strongly convex and smooth, so everything is nice and has the expected solutions. The equivalence between this problem and the one stated can be noted via stationarity conditions of the problem (and strong duality), while uniqueness of the solution follows from strong convexity everywhere in the domain.

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot! This is exactly what I looked for! :)
One question: Does the new function to optimize (let's call it J) hold $J(u) \geq c_1 ||u||^2_{H^1 (\Omega)} - c_2 $, where $c_1, c_2 > 0$?

Comment: Is $u$ a solution here? If not, this is not necessarily clear to me. If $g=0$, pick $u(x)=C>0$, then the right hand quantity goes as $C$ but $J(u)$ is zero.

Comment: I asked my colleague about the $u$. He thinks that $u$ is arbitrarily. But he said that the inequation of Poincaré should help: $$ \int_{\Omega} | \nabla u |^2 dx + \int_{\partial \Omega} |u|^2 ds_x \geq c_P ||u||^2_{H^1(\Omega)} $$

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't really help to me :/ Does it help to you?

Comment: I guess what do you mean here by $\|\cdot\|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2$? I assumed this was just the $L^2$ norm on the Hardy space. If you're talking about the usual norm on a Sobolev space, then this might be different.